# CXF Interceptor only for Certain Endpoints

Tags: spring, cxf, interceptor

I have googled quite a while for this but couldn't find anything that solves my problem.

I am implementing a CXF Interceptor (AbstractPhaseInterceptor) and configure it in spring using the CXFBusImpl.

This enables the interceptor for all end points. What I want however is only enable this interceptor for specific end points. 
Is this possible?

Hope somebody can help :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Endpoint declaration understands interceptors too:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="...">
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
       ... interceptors here ...
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Same for outInterceptors and jaxrs.